# ip rule and route doesn't get respected

Tags: linux, ip, route, ip-routing, policy-routing

I'm trying to route `packets` based on their `source` `address`, and have added the following:

```
# ip rule add from 10.10.10.0/16 dev eth0 table foobar
# ip route add default via 100.100.100.1 dev eth0 table foobar
```

Testing the routing however gives me wrong `via` address:

```
# ip route get 4.3.2.1 from 10.10.10.1
4.3.2.1 from 10.10.10.1 via 100.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

Why doesn't this get respected?

This is my regular `routes`

```
# ip route list
default via 100.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

and

```
# ip route show table foobar
default via 100.100.100.1 dev eth0
```

and

```
# ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local
32765:  from 10.10.10.0/16 iif eth0 lookup foobar
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: Isn't 10.10.10.0/16 a host address in the 10.10.0.0 subnet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue isn't issue. In rule you use not only source address, but also input interface match. So, there are two ways to solve your "problem":

1. Don't use the `dev eth0` in the rule
2. Add `iif eth0` in the `ip route get...` command. The `iif` option allows you use non-local addresses in the `ip route get` command, so you can use something like:
   `ip route get 4.3.2.1 from 10.10.20.253 iif eth0`

Comment: I was wondering if that was it. Since they're both routed to eth0, it might just be returning the default because that's the top rule for that interface. I'd add a new interface on eth1, and see if that changed it.

Comment: In the `ip route get` by default used the loopback interface if `iif` isn't specified. If you want the bloody details, you can look at source code ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L2868 )